# Set the number of visible items in a NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have a simple `NumberPicker` just like this:

[image: NumberPicker]

and I was wondering how I can make it show more elements above and below the selected element.

For example, in the picture you can see "9" above the selected element "10", and "11" right below it.

I would like to change the number of visible rows so it shows more elements like "7, 8, 9", then the selected element "10", then "11, 12, 13".

This is my code:

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />
```

and I've tried to change setting `android:layout_height` to `match_parent` and to a big number (e.g. 500dp) but it doesn't seen to work...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to find a workaround for this problem. You need to extend your `NumberPicker` class and need to change the

```
private static final int SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT = 3;
```

from three to more as much you wish, but it will display according to the available space.

You can find a library and sample [here](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker).

Comment: The Link is dead.

Comment: Updated the link !

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee How exactly did you change the value of private static final field? I'm also working on this and trying to follow your suggestion.

Comment: It's impossible to change private final field values

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is not way to do that, unless you rewrite whole numberpicker.